# Client JAX-RS Asynchronous request

Tags: java, rest, asynchronous, client, jax-rs

I want to implement an asynchronous JAX_RS client
I have five web service Rest, I need to launch these services at the same time without waiting for the response of the first service launched.

Here is my client code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        while (true) {
            for (int i=11;i<=15;i++){
                launcherPS(i);
            }
        }   
    }

    static void launcherPS(int id){
        ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
        String name="LampPostZ"+id;
        WebTarget target = client.target(getBaseURI(name));
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Launching of PresenceSensor "+id+"........");

        String state = target.path("PresenceSensor/"+id).path("getState")
                .request().accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(String.class);
        System.out.println("state Presence Sensor "+id+" = " + state);
        if (state.equals("On")) {
            target.path("PresenceSensor/"+id).path("change").request()
                    .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(String.class);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Presence Sensor  shut down, state= "
                    + state);

        }
    }
    private static URI getBaseURI(String project) {// chemin de l'application
        return UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:8081/"+project).build();                                                                            
    }
}
```

How to put it asynchronous (launching the 5 sensor at the same time)?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you have a while true ? Once your loop is over all work is done right ?

You will need to put each call in its own thread.

Here is my take : launch each call in its thread, then wait for each response, and exits the app.

You can use this code :

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

// Each call will be started here
List<Future<Integer>> futureList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 11; i <= 15; i++) {
    final int index = i;
    Future<Integer> future = executor.submit(() -> {
        // do your stuff here
        return index;
    });
    futureList.add(future);
}

// This will wait for each call to finish
for (Future<Integer> integerFuture : futureList) {
    integerFuture.get();
}

// everything's done, no need to wait indefinitely
```

Comment: I put while true because I need an infinite loop.
in fact, I have 5 presence sensors, I will put them in function all the time, for that I would like to launch them at the same time by a single client, instead of creating 5 client and each client launches a sensor.
The code that I put allows to launch the sensors in a successive way. ie the launch of a sensor starts only if the first one finishes its operation.

Comment: Ok, anyway you can use threads as I wrote to achieve asynchronism.

Comment: the syntax of the code is wrong `Future<Integer> future = executor.submit(() -> {
        // do your stuff here
        return index;
    });`

Comment: What version of java do you use ?

Comment: I use the version 8 of Java

Comment: No compile issue for me. Check your environment settings. One problem at runtime though, Collections.emptyList() is immutable, so futureList.add(future); was throwing an UnsupportedOperationException. I edited the code accordingly.

Comment: it shows me that submit must be: submit(Callable<T> arg0) or submit(Runnable arg0) or submit(Runnable arg0, T arg1). A question: why `return index;`? I have not a function.

Comment: It really looks like you have a version of java below 8. What error does the compiler display ? The return index is optionnal, but could be useful to know which thread just finished.